# WPF DataGrid Design Effect

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid in my application and I am looking to add a click effect to generate more data and slide into the Grid.

So here is my DataGrid:

[image]

As you can see what i want to happen is when the arrow is clicked for the information to slide of and get replaced by this:

[image]

I am wondering is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would group the UI elements for "Select Episode" and "Select Chapter" change the display from one group to the other using animations.

I cannot give you a complete code example, but I would try this:

- Create a `Grid` control with two columns and one row
- Take you existing UI elements and put the in the left column
- Place the UI elements for displaying the episode details (the chapters) in the right column of the `Grid`
- Initially the width of the left column is 100% and the with of the right column is 0%
- Assuming the "arrow" from the first image is a "episode details" button: Add an event trigger for the button (see example code below)
- Inside the event trigger: Start an anmimation with `BeginStoryboard` which changes the widths of the two columns over a short amount of time. A [DoubleAnimation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimation) should do. In the StoryBoard you somehow need to address the target element which you want to change (the column widths of the `Grid`)
- Add a new property `SelectedEpisode` to your view model which includes the list of chapters
- When the episode details button is clicked: Set the `SelectedEpisode` property in the view model
- In the right column: Bind the UI elements for displaying the chapters to sub-properties of the `SelectedEpisode` property in the view model

If the visual effect with the two columns does not look good, perhaps another idea would be to use the animation to change the x coordinates of the two groups of elements in combination with a `Canvas`.

Here is example for a `Button` with an `EventTrigger` and some dummy code for animation:

```
    <Button>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" >
                <BeginStoryboard>
                  <StoryBoard TargetName="..." TargetProperty="...">
                 ... change column with here
                  </StoryBoard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will get back to you when i have put this all together!